# Save State of Java GUI

Tags: java

I'm pretty new to creating GUIs in Java, so I'm not sure if this is easy or difficult to do. I'm creating a random name chooser, where the user inputs names and then randomly selects some. I am trying to have it save the names entered after the application is closed, and then placed back when it is reopened. I am not sure the best way to go about this; I've looked around a little bit and read a bit about serialization, but it isn't making a lot of sense. Here's my code from NetBeans so far.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.*;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
import javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException;
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import sun.applet.Main;
import sun.audio.*;
public class NameChooser extends javax.swing.JFrame {

private ArrayList <Integer> integers;
private Integer index;
private DefaultListModel dlm;

    /**
     * Creates new form NameChooser
     */
    public NameChooser() 
    {
        initComponents();
        integers = new ArrayList <Integer>();
        dlm = new DefaultListModel();

    }
public Integer generateNum()
    {
       int pings = 0;
       do
       {
           pings = 0;
           int temp = (int)(Math.random() * dlm.getSize());
           index = new Integer(temp);
           for (int k = 0; k < integers.size(); k++)
           {
               if ((integers.get(k).compareTo(index)) == 0)
               {
                    pings++;
               }      
           }

       }   
       while (pings != 0); 
       return index;
    }
    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        selectButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        names = new javax.swing.JList<>();
        nameField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        resetButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
        removeButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jMenuBar1 = new javax.swing.JMenuBar();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        selectButton.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Dialog", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
        selectButton.setText("Choose Name");
        selectButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                selectButtonActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        names.setFixedCellHeight(30);
        names.setFixedCellWidth(200);
        names.setLayoutOrientation(javax.swing.JList.VERTICAL_WRAP);
        jScrollPane2.setViewportView(names);

        nameField.setText("Enter Name Here");
        nameField.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                nameFieldActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        resetButton.setText("Reset");
        resetButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                resetButtonActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        removeButton.setText("Remove");
        removeButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                removeButtonActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        setJMenuBar(jMenuBar1);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(349, 349, 349)
                        .addComponent(selectButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 197, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(resetButton))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGap(23, 23, 23)
                                .addComponent(removeButton)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addContainerGap()
                                .addComponent(nameField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 117, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                .addGap(18, 18, 18)))
                        .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 589, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addGap(64, 64, 64))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(119, 119, 119)
                .addComponent(nameField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 28, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(26, 26, 26)
                .addComponent(removeButton)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(selectButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 32, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(26, 26, 26))
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(84, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 418, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(resetButton)
                .addGap(40, 40, 40))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        



    private void selectButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
            integers.add(generateNum());
            if (integers.size() <= dlm.getSize())
            {


            int [] indexes = new int [integers.size()];
            for (int i = 0; i < indexes.length; i++)
            {
                indexes[i] = integers.get(i).intValue();
            }
            try {
         // Open an audio input stream.
         File soundFile = new File("C:\\Users\\Oskar\\Desktop\\sound.wav");
         AudioInputStream audioIn = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundFile);
         // Get a sound clip resource.
         Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
         // Open audio clip and load samples from the audio input stream.
         clip.open(audioIn);
         clip.start();
      } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
            //playSound();

            names.setSelectedIndices(indexes);
            }
    }                                            


    private void resetButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        integers.clear();
        int[]indexes = new int[0];
        names.setSelectedIndices(indexes);
    }                                           

    private void nameFieldActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
       //Add Name
       int size = nameField.getDocument().getLength();
       if (size <= 0)
           return;
       dlm.addElement(nameField.getText());
       nameField.setText("");
       names.setModel(dlm);
    }                                         

    private void removeButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
        if (names.getSelectedIndex() != -1)
        {
            dlm.remove(names.getSelectedIndex());
        }

    }                                            

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NameChooser.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NameChooser.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NameChooser.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NameChooser.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new NameChooser().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JMenuBar jMenuBar1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
    private javax.swing.JTextField nameField;
    private javax.swing.JList<String> names;
    private javax.swing.JButton removeButton;
    private javax.swing.JButton resetButton;
    private javax.swing.JButton selectButton;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Could I just make an array or arraylist containing the entered names, somehow save that to a file, then load that file upon running the program to import the names? Or possibly just save the state of the jList? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you find solution to your problem statement?

Comment: @asifsid88 everyone posted a different solution, I'm going through now and trying each one out. I'll update when I get one to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to serialize the state of a Java GUI, because many GUI objects are not serializable.

The `JList` class is declared as `Serializable`, so you may be able to serialize it.  (It depends on the types of the elements in the list.  They also have to be serializable.)

It is theoretically possible to write code that will traverse a GUI data structures, extract the state that needs to be saved into a serializable data structure, and then serialize it.  Then you need code to do the reverse; i.e. rebuild / repopulate the GUI from the saved state.  (But I suspect you would be better off dealing with this in a different way; e.g. using a custom "preferences" mechanism implemented using properties files or similar.)

However, your aim is to persist the data that you are displaying and updating in the GUI, it is better to do this at the "model" level.  Depending on the nature of the model, and the requirements for handling the data, there are other alternatives to object serialization that are:

- more efficient,
- more scalable,
- more resistant to data loss; e.g. when an application crashes,
- more able to cope with *evolution* of the application, and
- able to be accessed from outside of Java.

Comment: Thanks for the info; I put each name into an ArrayList, then serialized it and was able to read/write with that. Appreciate it!

Comment: Although `JList` does declare `Serializable`, I believe that's only because they fear removing the interface will break some old code. The docs clearly say that components should not be serialised because you can't rely on the serialised data being readable in a later version of Java. You _can_ use some other API to save them as XML if you really must store the entire component, but it's going to be much faster to serialise exactly what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at `java.util.prefs.Preferences`. When your app closes, you can do something like...

```
public void savePreferences() {
    Preferences preferences = Preferences.userNodeForPackage(NameChooser.class);
    preferences.put("names", "name1, name2, name3");
}
```

You'll have to extract the names from `JList` and convert it to a comma delimited string (use `StringBuilder`). You should be able to get it using `JList.getModel`. Then when your app loads...

```
public void loadPreferences() {
    Preferences preferences = Preferences.userNodeForPackage(NameChooser.class);
    namesAsString = preferences.get("names", null);
}
```

`String.split` the namesAsString and whack it back in your `JList`. Make sense? You got a NullPointerException because I bet you just copy pasted the code. Here's a more simple example:

```
package example;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.prefs.Preferences;

public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Preferences pref = Preferences.userNodeForPackage(Example.class);
        String namesAsString = pref.get("names", "empty");
        // on first run, this will be empty because you have not saved anything yet
        // on succeeding runs, you should see something like:
        // Names in preferences: name1Mon May 07 07:15:46 BST 2018, name2Mon May 07 07:15:46 BST 2018
        System.out.println("Names in preferences: " + namesAsString);

        // simulating new name every time this is run, hence the date
        String name1 = "name1" + new Date();
        String name2 = "name2" + new Date();
        pref.put("names", name1 + ", " + name2);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried what you did, and I keep getting a NullPointerException. I got the names into a delimited string, did preferences.put, but namesAsString gets initialized to null. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There was nothing saved in `preferences` and you didn't do validation that why you got a NPE. That's my guess. Updated my answer, I hope you'll get the idea now.

Comment: One caveat of this approach is that preferences have a (very aggressive) maximum length limit. Because of that, you might want to store one value per preference, instead of putting multiple into the same value.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a use of Database if you would like to in order to maintain your state. But seems like, just for tiny thing maintaining a database would be costly.

Rather save them in a flat file `.txt` file and define your own delimiter.

For example:

1. Insert each record in a new line.
2. Each value in a record is separated by a pipe `|`.

Sample of file data:

```
First Name | Second Name | Anything  
First Name 2 | Second Name 2 | Anything else
```

Then once your application loads up, check for the existence of this file and then read this file. You will need to create your parser which understands your file syntax. And then populate your GUI as per these data (if any).
 Update the file if your application requires so

Another approach would be to Create a java class "State" (normal POJO) and then serialize it and save it in your file. When the application loads up, then deserialize it and use in your application.
The problem is:

1. Overhead of serializing and de-serializing and storing the file
2. Ensure when object upgrades then you need to maintain old fields (legacy) else your deserializing won't work (common problem of serialization/deserialization).

Google topic around this for more details.